# How to center div when printed

Tags: html, css, printing

I am building a solution that includes printing an invoice out of the web browser. I am willing to live with a few browser quarks.

I would like to make my content center in the printed page instead of on the left side as the browser is wanting to do. I have tried setting right and left margins to auto but to no avail.  I have also tried googling around but based on the very little I was able to find, I'm fearing  that it won't be possible.

Comment: I'm surprised this question has been closed. I'm soon going to be looking for answers to similar questions due toa simililar approaching issue. I also need to know if there's any way I can control physical print size too. May end up converting web pages to PDF before printing if I can make that process fast enough...

Comment: I'm surprised this got closed too, specifically for the *reason* it was closed. It could probably have been avoided if there was some code in the post, because after all - that's what the question is about. No way to tackle the issue without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a printing style sheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

Note the `media="print"`.

In `print.css`, you can add margins and centering and whatnot.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. The problem is that it seems my `margin: 0 auto;` isn't working when printing.

Comment: @Icode4food: If that's the case: why didn't you say so? Can we see your HTML markup and print stylesheet then?

Comment: @Icode4food: Is the div `position:absolute;`?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, to make the `margin:auto;` work, we need to provide approximate width. So, it is rendered at the center.

```
<style type="text/css">
#content{ margin: 0 auto; width:500px;}
</style>
```

Comment: `px` doesn't translate well to print, it's better to avoid using them as a unit of measurement for printing on paper. If anything, use `pt`.